# Error installing rvm 2.3.0 , installation halts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install rvm 2.3.0 for 2 days but getting below error.I tried using "rvm install ruby-2.3.0" command.It did not work.Then again I did

```
rvm get master
rvm install 2.3.1
```

Again got the same error.Anyone have an idea regarding this.thanks in advance.

```
Warning, new version of rvm available '1.27.0', you are using older version '1.26.11'.
You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/smrutisumanpanda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.0 - #downloading ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.0 - #extracting ruby-2.3.0 to /Users/smrutisumanpanda/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0....
ruby-2.3.0 - #configuring.......
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/smrutisumanpanda/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/smrutisumanpanda/.rvm/log/1475218763_ruby-2.3.0/configure.log
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for cd using physical directory... cd -P
checking whether CFLAGS is valid... no
configure: error: something wrong with CFLAGS="-g -O2 "
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest.Still I am stuck in it.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue resolved.I updated my OS mac version 10.10.2 to 10.10.5.After that i tried installing rvm (rvm install 2.3.0) and it got installed.